# Automatic generate code - add getters/setters for method invocation, not object creation

Tags: java, eclipse, setter, getter

I need to fill up some Java business or entity objects in a method.

```
User user = new User();

user.setFirstName();
user.setLastName();
user.setCountry();
user.setLanguage();
user.setStreet();
user.setHouseNumber();
user.setTown();
user.setUserName();
```

Is there a way to generate those setters automatically?
I already have this object with getters/setters, now I need to create this instance.
A solutions is needed ***for method invocation, not object creation.***

I use the eclipse IDE. Something like:

```
User user = new User();
```

***Right click -> Add Source -> Add all setters (ALT+CTRL+exotic-key-combination)***
Or an alternative way?

Just to say that this will same me a lot of plotting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would recommend [Project Lombock](http://projectlombok.org/) for getter/setter generation.

It can also generate `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString`.

It uses an annotation processor to generate the code at compile time so that it doesn't clutter up your classes.

So a simple class :

```
public class Example {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

With getters,setters,equals and hashCode becomes:

```
public class Example {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.firstName);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lastName);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Example other = (Example) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.firstName, other.firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.lastName, other.lastName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which is a right mess. With Lombock this can be done like so:

```
@Data
public class Example {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

And if we decompile the compiled class we get:

```
public class Example {

    public Example() {
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Example)) {
            return false;
        }
        Example other = (Example) o;
        if (!other.canEqual(this)) {
            return false;
        }
        Object this$firstName = getFirstName();
        Object other$firstName = other.getFirstName();
        if (this$firstName != null ? !this$firstName.equals(other$firstName) : other$firstName != null) {
            return false;
        }
        Object this$lastName = getLastName();
        Object other$lastName = other.getLastName();
        return this$lastName != null ? this$lastName.equals(other$lastName) : other$lastName == null;
    }

    public boolean canEqual(Object other) {
        return other instanceof Example;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int PRIME = 31;
        int result = 1;
        Object $firstName = getFirstName();
        result = result * 31 + ($firstName != null ? $firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        Object $lastName = getLastName();
        result = result * 31 + ($lastName != null ? $lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (new StringBuilder()).append("Example(firstName=").append(getFirstName()).append(", lastName=").append(getLastName()).append(")").toString();
    }
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

So all the code is there, including a `toString`.

Comment: I have an entity object with getters and setters. What I would love to have is shortcut/context-tool that generates code to fill this object. So, generate all user.setXXXX(), without typing that all. I will fill in the contents afterswords. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). Using this you can annotate your class with @Data and library will generate getters and setters.

Comment: I have an entity object with getters and setters. What I would love to have is shortcut/context-tool that generates code to fill this object. So, generate all user.setXXXX(), without typing that all. I will fill in the contents afterswords. Thanks!